# Facebook Sdk blocked : How to detect if a user is using Ghostery?

Tags: javascript, facebook, angularjs, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

In order to make calls on the Facebook Graph Api, users have to log in and accept my application on my website. With Ghostery enabled and Facebook Connect blocked, it just fails to load the sdk and I get a nice `GET http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT` in my Chrome console. Obviously it breaks the feature.

**Is there a nice and simple client side way of detecting Ghostery's blockings** so I can display a friendly message instead, asking the user to whitelist my website if he wants a full access to the features ?

FYI, I'm using Angularjs and use a provider to load the sdk and make the calls. This is how it looks :

```
function fbInit(appID) {

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)){
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : appID,
            cookie     : true,  
            xfbml      : true,  
            version    : 'v2.1' 
        });
    }; 
}

this.setAppID = function(appID) {
    this.appID = appID;
};

this.$get = function() {
    var appID = this.appID;
    var self = this;
    fbInit(appID);

    return {
        /* Methods */
    };
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Facebook calls `fbAsyncInit` when the JS client has been loaded. If that function hasn't been run after a certain amount of time you can be relatively sure it has failed. One approach you could take is something like this.

```
window.fbLoaded = false;

setTimeout(function() {
    if (!fbLoaded) {
        // show error
    }
}, 5 * 1000);

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    window.fbLoaded = true;
    // hide error incase client took more than 5 seconds to load
    // continue running your code as usual
}
```

Comment: I don't really fancy using timeouts but it seems like this is the only solution for cross domain file loading... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to load the file yourself via XHR before initializing FB API, and abort/inform the user upon error with that request.

I assume you already have host permissions for `connect.facebook.net`

Answer (score 1):

In 2019 except anti-tracking browser extensions, some browsers' default behaviour is to block third party tracking cookies (e.g. firefox and maybe more) so I used [@Xan's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26504165/9574573) for my case for my Angular (2+) project. I am using [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to check for allowance. (You can check for browser compatibility of Fetch API in the link provided). Below you call `checkIfFacebookIsBlocked()` function as soon as possible in your app's initialization or after GDPR acceptance etc.

```
  checkIfFacebookIsBlocked() {
    const _this = this;
    fetch('https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js')
      .then(function() {
        console.log('Facebook sdk is allowed:');
        _this.initFacebookSdk();
      })
      .catch(function() {
        console.log('Facebook sdk is NOT allowed:');
        // handle the case that facebook is not allowed
      });
  }


  initFacebookSdk() {
    const _this = this;
    (window as any).fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : FACEBOOK_APP_ID, // fb App ID
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : FACEBOOK_SDK_VERSION // fb app's api version
      });
      FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
      // your code after Facebook sdk is loaded... (getLoginStatus(), login(), api('/me', ...) etc.)
    };
    (function(d, s, id) {
      let js;
      const fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an `onerror` handler to the script tag that loads the API that will trigger when the API request fails.

This can be much faster than setting a timeout and waiting on `fbAsyncInit`

Comment: Certain extension + browser combinations will *not* cause the `onerror` to fire.  I found out the hard way!